# Can NodeJS restart itself?

Tags: windows, linux, node.js

Is it possible for a NodeJS server to restart itself when a new plugin (custom idea of a plugin, not NPM) is installed?

Comment: You dont have to restart node. You just need infrastructure to let the running node process attach new plugins at run time

Comment: @Raynos how would I refresh plugins that have been updated or removed? My need compares well to Joomla/Drupal plugins/components. cheers

Comment: I'm working on [nCore](https://github.com/Raynos/nCore) which gives you infrastructure to add and remove modules at run time. All you need is to write a small module that watches the file system and adds new modules as they are dropped in the file system or removes and reloads modules as they are changed. I'll implement that at some point

Comment: @Raynos interesting, I will have a look at that, cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are using something that monitors that Node process (Forever or Monit), it's impossible for Node to restart itself.

Comment: Is it possible for Node to send a signal to Forever or Monit to trigger a restart? cheers

Comment: Would the new cluster feature allow for a restart? By "restart" I would like to unload all scripts and then reload plugin scripts (except those which do not exist any more)

Comment: The cluster feature works exactly like child_process.fork, so you can fork processes, kill them and spawn others. That's what you can do.